# How to check if key exists in the data from the server in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I get some JSON values from the server but I don't know if there will be a particular field or not.

Sometimes i get the response in this form

```
{
 "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited"
}
```

Where as sometimes i get reponse in this form

```
{
 "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited",
   "vehicle": "yes"
}
```

How to check if **vehicle** key exists in the javascript object.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't know if the object will be there or not then you can check with the `response['prop']` syntax. You can also check with the dot syntax, as is being done above, but I prefer this way. I got into this habit because the `response.prop` syntax won't work in Typescript unless the property is clearly known by the compiler.

```
if (serverResponse && serverResponse['vehicle']) {
    // vehicle key exists
    // do your stuff 
} else {
    // vehicle key Does Not exist
    // do your stuff 
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why your code answers the question.

Comment: @BobDalgleish - I added an explanation. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do the check like:

```
const obj = {
   "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
   "country":"Congo",
   "status":"invited",
   "vehicle": "yes"
};
```

- by using `in` operator: `if("vehicle" in obj){ -- }`
- by using `hasOwnProperty`:  `if(obj.hasOwnProperty("vehicle")){ -- }`
- by checking: `if(obj["vehicle"]){ -- }` or `if(obj.vehicle){ -- }`

Answer (score 2):

JS objects are very easy to check, since if you try to access it and it doesn't exist, no error is thrown. So you can simply check like this:

```
let response = {
   "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
   "country":"Congo",
   "status":"invited",
   "vehicle": "yes"
};

if(response.vehicle) { // or if(response["vehicle"])
    // do stuff
}
```

This works because if JS cannot find the property 'vehicle' in the object, it will fail this conditional. So if the property does exist, the code will enter the if block and you can use the data in the object.

Answer (score 1):

So first, assume the objects are stored as follows:

```
obj1 = {
 "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited"
}

obj2 = {
 "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited",
  "vehicle": "yes"
}
```

To check simply do

```
if('vehicle' in obj1){
 console.log(true)
}

if('vehicle' in obj2){
 console.log(true)
}
```

The output you get will be `false, true`

Also, you can use `hasOwnProperty` if you want. I.e.

```
obj1.hasOwnProperty('vehicle') // false
obj2.hasOwnProperty('vehicle') // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be needing

```
JsonObj.hasOwnProperty('key')
```

check this [refrence link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object/)